# How to retrieve object attributes to run some dynamic logic in Spring MVC view

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, view

I am having trouble dealing with the objects passing from controller in a Spring MVC app.
I want to pass an object from the home controller and want to receive the object ina view, that i am able to do.
But, I want to make some dynamic decision depending on that objects attributes in that view (here jsp page). Which i don't know how to do.
Can anybody please help me..

**My controller looks like:**

```
HashMap hm = usr.getRightsHM(usr.getId_user());
model.addAttribute("rights", hm);
return "index";
```

**index.jsp**

```
<p>${rights.get("RIGHT_FIRST_ATTRIBUTE")}</p>
```

This is working ok.

But, what if i wanted to run some logic depending on that value, like we do in normal java application using <% %> tag.. How to retrieve the attributes here to run some logic based on the values?
Please help.

Hi, I have went through the doc and tried to implement the logic this way..

```
<c:set var="i_right" scope="session" value="${rights.get("RIGHT_FIRST_ATTRIBUTE")"/> 
<c:if test="${i_right > 0}"> <li ... ></li> </c:if>
```

But it is giving warning as 'Undefined attribute name "RIGHT_FIRST_ATTRIBUTE"'
And then when i run it, it throws an error

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException:equal symbol expected
```

How to resolve it.. can you please help?

Comment: You can use core tab libraries to perform logic.

Comment: Please examine this [tutorial](http://www.journaldev.com/2090/jstl-tutorial-with-examples-jstl-core-tags).

Comment: I know that must be very easy. But, can you please give me a link where i can learn that spring specific thing.. or can you give me a very simple example.. Please don't mind i'm asking this way. Like if i run some logic <% if (${rights.get("RIGHT_FIRST_ATTRIBUTE")} == something) %> then do something.. etc.  how to do that

Comment: thank you very much @Uğur Güneri . I will check that.

Comment: Hi, I have went through the doc and tried to implement the logic this way.. 
<c:set var="i_right" scope="session" value="${rights.get("RIGHT_FIRST_ATTRIBUTE")"/>
<c:if test="${i_right > 0}">
<li ... ></li>
</c:if>
But it is throwing error on value="${rights.get("RIGHT_FIRST_ATTRIBUTE")"

How to resolve it.. can you please help?

Comment: Really sorry to bother you on this relatively small issue. I have been able to solve the issue. Thank you very much :)